# How to do a Spark dataframe(1 million rows) cartesian product with a list(1000 entries) efficiently to generate a new dataframe with 1 billion rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I want to take each row of a dataframe which has 1 million rows and generate 1000 rows from each row of it by taking a cross product with a list having 1000 entries thereby generating a dataframe with 1 billion rows. What is the best approach to do it efficiently.
I have tried with broadcasting the list and then using it while mapping each row of the dataframe. But this seems to be taking too much time.

```
 val mappedrdd = validationDataFrames.map(x => {
     val cutoffList : List[String] = cutoffListBroadcast.value
     val arrayTruthTableVal = arrayTruthTableBroadcast.value

     var listBufferRow: ListBuffer[Row] = new ListBuffer()

       for(cutOff <- cutoffList){
          val conversion = x.get(0).asInstanceOf[Int]
          val probability = x.get(1).asInstanceOf[Double]

          var columnName : StringBuffer = new StringBuffer
          columnName = columnName.append(conversion)

          if(probability > cutOff.toDouble){
              columnName = columnName.append("_").append("1")
          }else{
              columnName = columnName.append("_").append("0")
          }
          val index:Int  = arrayTruthTableVal.indexOf(columnName.toString)
          var listBuffer : ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer()
          listBuffer :+= cutOff

          for(i <- 1 to 4){
             if((index + 1) == i) listBuffer :+= "1" else listBuffer :+= "0"
          }
          val row = Row.fromSeq(listBuffer)
          listBufferRow = listBufferRow :+ row
        }

      listBufferRow

     })
```

Comment: have you considered using data sets ? you will benefit from built in optimizations, you can apply cross join for two tables

Comment: "But this seems to be taking too much time." How long does it take, and how long do you expect it to take? Producing a billion rows is going to be expensive.

Comment: Actually it never completes.
it gets stuck at  listBufferRow = listBufferRow :+ row
On taking the thread dump of the executors I can see that the thread to be stuck at listBufferRow = listBufferRow :+ row 
The same thing works fine on relatively smaller DF.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your spark version you can do:

**Spark 2.1.0**

Add the list as a column and explode. A simplified example:

```
val df = spark.range(5)
val exploded = df.withColumn("a",lit(List(1,2,3).toArray)).withColumn("a", explode($"a"))
df.show()

+---+---+
| id|  a|
+---+---+
|  0|  1|
|  0|  2|
|  0|  3|
|  1|  1|
|  1|  2|
|  1|  3|
|  2|  1|
|  2|  2|
|  2|  3|
|  3|  1|
|  3|  2|
|  3|  3|
|  4|  1|
|  4|  2|
|  4|  3|
+---+---+
```

For timing you can do:

```
def time[R](block: => R): Long = {
    val t0 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    t1 - t0
 }
  time(spark.range(1000000).withColumn("a",lit((0 until 1000).toArray)).withColumn("a", explode($"a")).count())
```

took 5.41 seconds on a 16 core computer with plenty of memory configured with default parallelism of 60.

**< Spark 2.1.0**

You can define a simple UDF.

```
 val xx = (0 until 1000).toArray.toSeq // replace with your list but turn it to seq
  val ff = udf(() => {xx})
  time(spark.range(1000000).withColumn("a",ff()).withColumn("a", explode($"a")).count())
```

Took on the same server as above 8.25 seconds